# PHP cURL: Reset Callback (CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION)

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have a code similar to the following:

```php
$ch = curl_init();
// ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function ($ch, $header_line) {
    // process $header_line...
    return strlen($header_line); // needed by curl
});
// ...
curl_exec($ch);
```

After that code I'd like to keep using `$ch` to re-use the connection, but I don't need the custom `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` callback anymore. How can I reset it? I tried setting it to `null` but it didn't work.

Comment: Does this help you [curl_reset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-reset.php) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the common options in an array and reset options between executions:

```php
$common_options = [
    CURLOPT_XXX => 'something'
    // ...
];
$ch = curl_init();

// First call: common + specific options
curl_setopt_array($ch, $common_options);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOO, 'something else');

curl_exec($ch);

// Second call: common options only
curl_reset($ch);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $common_options);

curl_exec($ch);
```